# Convert indicator to library

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a source code

```cpp
//@version=5
indicator("PA-Adaptive MACD + RSI Past + STD-Stepped", overlay = true)

//PA-Adaptive MACD w/ Variety Levels [Loxx]
import loxx/loxxexpandedsourcetypes/3
import loxx/loxxmas/1
import loxx/loxxpaaspecial/1
SM02 = 'Zero-Line Cross'
SM03 = 'Signal Crossover'
SM04 = 'Levels Crossover'
RMA(x, t) =>
    EMA1 = x
    EMA1 := na(EMA1[1]) ? x : (x - nz(EMA1[1])) * (1/t) + nz(EMA1[1])
    EMA1
EMA(x, t) =>
    EMA1 = x
    EMA1 := na(EMA1[1]) ? x : (x - nz(EMA1[1])) * (2 / (t + 1)) + nz(EMA1[1])
    EMA1
variant(type, src, len) =>
    sig = 0.0
    if type == "SMA"
        sig := ta.sma(src, len) 
    else if type == "EMA"
        sig := EMA(src, len) 
    else if type == "WMA"
        sig := ta.wma(src, len)   
    else if type == "RMA"
        sig := RMA(src, len)  
    sig
greencolor = #2DD204
redcolor = #D2042D
lightgreencolor = #96E881 
lightredcolor =  #DF4F6C
smthtype = "Kaufman"
srcin = "Close"
matype = "EMA"
sigtype = "EMA"
signalMode = SM03
sigper = 8
fregcycles = 1.5
fregfilter = 1.0
sregcycles = 3.0
sregfilter = 1.0
sigregcycles = 1.
sigregfilter = 1.0
levelstype = "Floating"
FlPeriod = 35
FlUp  = 90
FlDn = 10
colorbars = false
showsignals = false
kfl=0.666
ksl=0.0645
amafl = 2
amasl = 30
haclose = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
haopen = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
hahigh = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
halow = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
hamedian = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hl2)
hatypical = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hlc3)
haweighted = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hlcc4)
haaverage = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, ohlc4)
src = switch srcin
    "Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rclose()
    "Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.ropen()
    "High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rhigh()
    "Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rlow()
    "Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rmedian()
    "Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtypical()
    "Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rweighted()
    "Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.raverage()
    "Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.ravemedbody()
    "Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtrendb()
    "Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtrendbext()
    "HA Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haclose(haclose)
    "HA Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haopen(haopen)
    "HA High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hahigh(hahigh)
    "HA Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.halow(halow)
    "HA Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hamedian(hamedian)
    "HA Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatypical(hatypical)
    "HA Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haweighted(haweighted)
    "HA Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haaverage(haaverage)
    "HA Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haavemedbody(haclose, haopen)
    "HA Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatrendb(haclose, haopen, hahigh, halow)
    "HA Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatrendbext(haclose, haopen, hahigh, halow)
    "HAB Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habclose(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habopen(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habhigh(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hablow(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habmedian(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtypical(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habweighted(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habaverage(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habavemedbody(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtrendb(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    "HAB Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtrendbext(smthtype, amafl, amasl, kfl, ksl)
    => haclose
int flen = math.floor(loxxpaaspecial.paa(close, fregcycles, fregfilter))
flen := flen < 1 ? 1 : flen
int slen = math.floor(loxxpaaspecial.paa(close, sregcycles, sregfilter))
slen := slen < 1 ? 1 : slen
int siglen = math.floor(loxxpaaspecial.paa(close, sigregcycles, sigregfilter))
siglen := siglen < 1 ? 1 : siglen
fma = variant(matype, src, flen)
sloma = variant(matype, src, slen)
macd = fma - sloma
signal = variant(sigtype, macd, siglen)
flhi = 0., mid = 0., fllo = 0., 
if levelstype == "Floating"
    min = ta.lowest(macd, FlPeriod)
    max = ta.highest(macd, FlPeriod)
    rng = max-min
    flhi := min + FlUp * rng / 100.0
    mid := min + 0.5 * rng
    fllo := min + FlDn * rng / 100.0
else
    flhi := ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(macd, FlPeriod, FlUp) 
    mid := ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(macd, FlPeriod, (FlUp+FlDn)/2.0)
    fllo := ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(macd, FlPeriod, FlDn)
colorout = 
     signalMode == SM03 ? (macd > signal ? greencolor : redcolor) : 
     signalMode == SM02 ? (macd > 0 ? greencolor : redcolor) : 
     (macd > flhi ? greencolor : macd < fllo ? redcolor : color.gray)
// plot(macd, color = colorout, linewidth = 2)
// plot(signal, color = color.white, linewidth = 1)
// plot(0, color = bar_index % 2 ? color.gray : na)
// barcolor(colorbars ? colorout : na)
goLong = signalMode == SM03 ? ta.crossover(macd, signal) : signalMode == SM02 ? ta.crossover(macd, 0) : ta.crossover(macd, flhi)
goShort = signalMode == SM03 ? ta.crossunder(macd, signal) : signalMode == SM02 ? ta.crossunder(macd, 0) : ta.crossunder(macd, fllo)
// plotshape(goLong and showsignals, title = "Long", color = greencolor, textcolor = greencolor, text = "L", style = shape.triangleup, location = location.bottom, size = size.auto)
// plotshape(goShort and showsignals, title = "Short", color = redcolor, textcolor = redcolor, text = "S", style = shape.triangledown, location = location.top, size = size.auto)

//RSI Past
rsiLength = 6
rsiSource = close
rsiOverbought = 70
rsiOversold = 30
color aboveColor = color.green
color belowColor = color.red
color zeroColor = color.black
var color plotColor = zeroColor
var int lastBullish = na
var int lastBearish = na
var float reading = na
rsiValue = ta.rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
if rsiValue < rsiOversold
    lastBearish := bar_index
else if rsiValue > rsiOverbought
    lastBullish := bar_index
if lastBullish and lastBearish
    reading := lastBullish - lastBearish
if reading
    if reading > 0
        plotColor := aboveColor
    else if reading < 0
        plotColor := belowColor
    else
        plotColor := zeroColor
//readingPlot = plot(reading, title="RSI Pass", color=plotColor, style=plot.style_area, linewidth=3)

//STD-Stepped Fast Cosine Transform Moving Average [Loxx]
greencolor1 = #2DD204
redcolor1 = #D2042D 
_fastcosinetransform(float[] a, int tnn, bool inversefct)=>
    int j = 0
    int n2 = 0
    float sum = 0.
    float y1 = 0.
    float y2 = 0.
    float theta = 0.
    float wi = 0.
    float wpi = 0.
    float wr = 0.
    float wpr = 0.
    float wtemp = 0.
    float twr = 0.
    float twi = 0.
    float twpr = 0.
    float twpi = 0.
    float twtemp = 0.
    float ttheta = 0.
    int i = 0
    int i1 = 0
    int i2 = 0
    int i3 = 0
    int i4 = 0
    float c1 = 0.
    float c2 = 0.
    float h1r = 0.
    float h1i = 0.
    float h2r = 0.
    float h2i = 0.
    float wrs = 0.
    float wis = 0.
    int nn = 0
    int n = 0
    int mmax = 0
    int m = 0
    int istep = 0
    int isign = 0
    float tempr = 0.
    float tempi = 0.
    while true
        if (tnn == 1) 
            y1 := array.get(a, 0)
            y2 := array.get(a, 1)
            array.set(a, 0, 0.5 * (y1 + y2))
            array.set(a, 1, 0.5 * (y1 - y2))
            if inversefct
                array.set(a, 0, array.get(a, 0) * 2)
                array.set(a, 1, array.get(a, 1) * 2)
                break
        wi := 0
        wr := 1
        theta := math.pi / tnn
        wtemp := math.sin(theta * 0.5)
        wpr := -2.0 * wtemp * wtemp
        wpi := math.sin(theta)
        sum := 0.5 * (array.get(a, 0) - array.get(a, tnn))
        array.set(a, 0, 0.5 * (array.get(a, 0) + array.get(a, tnn)))
        n2 := tnn + 2
        for jx = 2 to tnn / 2  
            wtemp := wr
            wr := wtemp * wpr - wi * wpi + wtemp
            wi := wi * wpr + wtemp * wpi + wi
            y1 := 0.5 * (array.get(a, jx - 1) + array.get(a, n2 - jx - 1))
            y2 := array.get(a, jx - 1) - array.get(a, n2 - jx - 1)
            array.set(a, jx - 1, y1 - wi * y2)
            array.set(a, n2 - jx - 1, y1 + wi * y2)
            sum := sum + wr * y2
        ttheta := 2.0 * math.pi / tnn
        c1 := 0.5
        c2 := -0.5
        isign := 1
        n := tnn
        nn := tnn / 2
        j := 1
        for ii = 1 to nn  
            i := 2 * ii - 1
            if (j > i) 
                tempr := array.get(a, j - 1)
                tempi := array.get(a, j)
                array.set(a, j - 1, array.get(a, i - 1))
                array.set(a, j, array.get(a, i))
                array.set(a, i - 1, tempr)
                array.set(a, i, tempi)
            m := n / 2
            while (m >= 2 and j > m) 
                j := j - m
                m := m / 2
            j := j + m
        mmax := 2
        while (n > mmax) 
            istep := 2 * mmax
            theta := 2.0 * math.pi / (isign * mmax)
            wpr := -2.0 * math.pow(math.sin(0.5 * theta), 2)
            wpi := math.sin(theta)
            wr := 1.0
            wi := 0.0
            for ii = 1 to mmax / 2  
                m := 2 * ii - 1
                for jj = 0 to (n - m) / istep  
                    i := m + jj * istep
                    j := i + mmax
                    tempr := wr * array.get(a, j - 1) - wi * array.get(a, j)
                    tempi := wr * array.get(a, j) + wi * array.get(a, j - 1)
                    array.set(a, j - 1, array.get(a, i - 1) - tempr)
                    array.set(a, j, array.get(a, i) - tempi)
                    array.set(a, i - 1, array.get(a, i - 1) + tempr)
                    array.set(a, i, array.get(a, i) + tempi)
                wtemp := wr
                wr := wr * wpr - wi * wpi + wr
                wi := wi * wpr + wtemp * wpi + wi
            mmax := istep
        twpr := -2.0 * math.pow(math.sin(0.5 * ttheta), 2)
        twpi := math.sin(ttheta)
        twr := 1.0 + twpr
        twi := twpi
        for ix = 2 to tnn / 4 + 1  
            i1 := ix + ix - 2
            i2 := i1 + 1
            i3 := tnn + 1 - i2
            i4 := i3 + 1
            wrs := twr
            wis := twi
            h1r := c1 * (array.get(a, i1) + array.get(a, i3))
            h1i := c1 * (array.get(a, i2) - array.get(a, i4))
            h2r := -c2 * (array.get(a, i2) + array.get(a, i4))
            h2i := c2 * (array.get(a, i1) - array.get(a, i3))
            array.set(a, i1, h1r + wrs * h2r - wis * h2i)
            array.set(a, i2, h1i + wrs * h2i + wis * h2r)
            array.set(a, i3, h1r - wrs * h2r + wis * h2i)
            array.set(a, i4, -h1i + wrs * h2i + wis * h2r)
            twtemp := twr
            twr := twr * twpr - twi * twpi + twr
            twi := twi * twpr + twtemp * twpi + twi
        h1r := array.get(a, 0)
        array.set(a, 0, h1r + array.get(a, 1))
        array.set(a, 1, h1r - array.get(a, 1))
        array.set(a, tnn, array.get(a, 1))
        array.set(a, 1, sum)
        j := 4
        while (j <= tnn) 
            sum := sum + array.get(a, j - 1)
            array.set(a, j - 1, sum)
            j := j + 2
        if (inversefct)
            for jx = 0 to tnn 
                array.set(a, jx, array.get(a, jx) * 2 / tnn)
        break
    a
_filt(src, len, filter)=>
    price = src
    filtdev = filter * ta.stdev(src, len)
    price := math.abs(price - price[1]) < filtdev ? price[1] : price
    price
smthtype1 = "Kaufman"
srcin1 = "HAB Trend Biased (Extreme)"
windowper = "256"
smthcutoff = 11
filterop = "FCT MA"
filter = 1
filterperiod = 10
colorbars1 = true
showSigs = true
kfl1=0.666
ksl1=0.0645
amafl1 = 2
amasl1 = 30
haclose1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
haopen1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
hahigh1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
halow1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
hamedian1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hl2)
hatypical1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hlc3)
haweighted1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, hlcc4)
haaverage1 = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, ohlc4)
src1 = switch srcin1
    "Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rclose()
    "Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.ropen()
    "High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rhigh()
    "Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rlow()
    "Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rmedian()
    "Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtypical()
    "Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rweighted()
    "Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.raverage()
    "Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.ravemedbody()
    "Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtrendb()
    "Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.rtrendbext()
    "HA Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haclose(haclose1)
    "HA Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haopen(haopen1)
    "HA High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hahigh(hahigh1)
    "HA Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.halow(halow1)
    "HA Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hamedian(hamedian1)
    "HA Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatypical(hatypical1)
    "HA Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haweighted(haweighted1)
    "HA Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haaverage(haaverage1)
    "HA Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.haavemedbody(haclose1, haopen1)
    "HA Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatrendb(haclose1, haopen1, hahigh1, halow1)
    "HA Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hatrendbext(haclose1, haopen1, hahigh1, halow1)
    "HAB Close" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habclose(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Open" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habopen(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB High" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habhigh(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Low" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.hablow(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Median" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habmedian(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Typical" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtypical(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Weighted" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habweighted(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Average" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habaverage(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Average Median Body" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habavemedbody(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Trend Biased" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtrendb(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    "HAB Trend Biased (Extreme)" => loxxexpandedsourcetypes.habtrendbext(smthtype1, amafl1, amasl1, kfl1, ksl1)
    => haclose1
src1 := filterop == "Both" or filterop == "Price" and filter > 0 ? _filt(src1, filterperiod, filter) : src1
Window = str.tonumber(windowper) 
n = int(math.log(Window) / math.log(2))
N = int(math.max(math.pow(2, n), 16))
var aa = array.new<float>(N + 1, 0.)
for i = 0 to N - 1
    array.set(aa, i, nz(src1[i])) 
M = array.size(aa)
end = M - 1
smthcutoff := int(math.min(smthcutoff, M))
_fastcosinetransform(aa, N, false)
for k = 0 to end 
    if k >= smthcutoff
        array.set(aa, k, 0.)
_fastcosinetransform(aa, N, true)
out = array.get(aa, 0) 
out := filterop == "Both" or filterop == "FCT MA" and filter > 0 ? _filt(out, filterperiod, filter) : out
sig = out[1]
goLong_pre = ta.crossover(out, sig)
goShort_pre = ta.crossunder(out, sig)
contSwitch = 0
contSwitch := nz(contSwitch[1])
contSwitch := goLong_pre ? 1 : goShort_pre ? -1 : contSwitch
goLong1 = goLong_pre and ta.change(contSwitch)
goShort1 = goShort_pre and ta.change(contSwitch)
//plot(out,"FCT MA", color = contSwitch == 1  ? greencolor1 : redcolor1, linewidth = 3)
//barcolor(colorbars1 ? contSwitch == 1 ? greencolor1 : redcolor1 : na)
// plotshape(showSigs and goLong1, title = "Long", color = color.yellow, textcolor = color.yellow, text = "L", style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, size = size.tiny)
// plotshape(showSigs and goShort1, title = "Short", color = color.fuchsia, textcolor = color.fuchsia, text = "S", style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, size = size.tiny)

//Condition
buy = contSwitch == 1 and colorout == greencolor and macd < 0 and plotColor == color.green
sell = contSwitch != 1 and colorout == redcolor and macd > 0 and plotColor == color.red
plotshape(buy, title='Buy', text='Buy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title='Sell', text='Sell', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.tiny)
```

In the code, i want to mark buy and sell positions over conditions based on other indicators.
To do that, I need to bundle 2-3 or 4 public code indicators on tradingview.
But now, the number of indicator codes has increased a lot and now, from many buy-sell indicators I need to continue to combine it into a single indicator.
However, renaming variables is quite boring, so I tried using library.

I have tried doing it like this:

```cpp
export fun() =>
     buy
```

But after I did the export and tried to import using the library on the script I failed again.

```cpp
import macketoi0326/MyLibrary/4 as f
v = f.fun()
plotshape(v, title='Buy', text='Buy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white) , 0), size=size.tiny)
```

So is there a way to convert from indicator to library to get buy-sell condition variables quickly? Or will I have to do the work of changing the variable continuously? Or will I create a function and throw all my indicators into that function and then output?